# How to convert binary fraction into hexadecimal in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary, hex

How can i convert a binary fraction or a decimal fraction into hex in *Java*?

What is the  algorithm to do that?
for example i want (11.110)2 be converted into (3.C)16

and which data type do I need to hold the hex fraction ?

plz help.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you add a sample of what you have try ?

Comment: What is a hex fraction?  Is it just a fraction with both numerator and denominator? So Dec 10/11 would be 0xA/0xB?  Can you explain the problem better? (Also, it's Java, not JAVA.)

Comment: The algorithm is the same as converting decimal.  You can optimise it slightly but I would just do it the same to start with.

Comment: `Integer`, `Long` and `BigInteger` already have this feature for whole numbers. You could simply convert between integer and floating point number by shifting the radix point.

Comment: i know the algorithm to convert binary fraction into decimal fraction

Comment: If you want to do it manually instead of using built-in methods, you could convert 4 binary digits at a time, to the corresponding hex value.

Comment: can you post the built in methods @Lonenebula

Comment: I posted the most relevant built-in methods. They only work on whole numbers, but the answer gives you an idea of how to work around that.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not meant to be a complete guide on how to make a fully working program that converts from one radix to another, but it mentions most of the steps you'd have to do if you want to use the built-in methods that are available.

There are no built-in methods for converting floating-point numbers, but there are built-in methods for converting integers from/to any radix between 2-36. If you only need to convert between binary and hexadecimal and nothing else, you could also do it manually (see below the line further down), but I recommend using these methods otherwise.

If you remove the radix point `.` from the number (in its `String`-representation), you get a whole number, but keep track of how many digits were to the right of the radix point.

Here are three ways to convert a whole number from a `String` with any radix:

- `Integer.parseInt(String val, int radix)` will convert to `int`.
- `Long.parseLong(String val, int radix)` will convert to `long`.
- `new BigInteger(String val, int radix)` will convert to `BigInteger`.

You should then convert the number to a `double` or `BigDecimal`, and make sure you get the radix point back in place, by dividing by the correct number. For instance, you can turn (1234)6 into (12.34)6 by dividing it by 6².

Now you are halfway done, and basically go backwards to convert the number back to a `String` (but with some other radix).

At the step where you want to convert from `int`/`long`/`BigInteger` to a `String`, use `toString`:

- `Integer.toString(int val, int radix)` will convert from `int`.
- `Long.toString(long val, int radix)` will convert from `long`.
- `val.toString(int radix)` will convert from `BigInteger`.

Remember to insert the radix point again, and you're done.

---

To convert from binary to hex manually, you do [the same as you would do if they were whole numbers](http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-Binary-to-Hexadecimal), with few differences.

Divide the binary number into sets of 4 consecutive digits, starting at the radix point, going both left and right. Add leading/trailing zeros as needed. The rest is as explained in the link.

For instance: `101011.011` is divided into `0010 1011 . 0110` which becomes `2B.6` after converting each set to hexadecimal.